# Plot circles with centre and radius

Tags: java, graph, geometry, raster, coords

I am currently in the progress of using WritableRaster and it's setPixed method, and I need it to not set only one pixel, but a 'circle' with the radius of r.
What I am thinking about is something like this:

```
for(int y = -r; y < r; y++)
{
    for(int x = -r; x < r; x++)
    {
         raster.setPixel(x,y,color);
 }}
```

The question is, would this work to make a circle, if so, how would I make it go through all the pixels inside?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Sorry I did not make this clear- I am making a rubber tool on a transparent canvas, thus, if I draw a circle with transparent color, it won't delete what was there before... This is why I am using setPixel.

EDIT EDIT: This is what the output of the code is (on g2d, using drawLine with same values so it only fills one pixel as in the method setPixel): 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ONWe.png

EDIT EDIT EDIT: If anyone wants to use this code for the same reason, I recommend using BufferedImage.setRGB() because it's much quicker. If you don't know what to do with the color (last parameter), use something like:

```
...
buffImg.setRGB(x,y,new Color(r,g,b,a).getRGB());
...
```

Comment: Did you try this code? What did you get?

Comment: This is basic computer graphics, there's tons of materials about it, you can even start with Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Comment: Do you HAVE to use a WritableRaster? If this is part of a BufferedImage, you should paint the circle using the BufferedImage`s Graphics context. (If it is not part of a BufferedImage, (I wonder where it comes from and what you are doing there, but) one could even consider "wrapping" the WriteableRaster in a BufferedImage, to employ the convenient methods of drawing into it via a Graphics object).

Comment: Sorry guys - I accidently deleted the question and forgot to put it back... The question is, would this work to make a circle, if so, how would I make it go through all the pixels inside?

Comment: @Marco13 Sorry I did not make this clear- I am making a rubber tool on a transparent canvas, thus, if I draw a circle with transparent color, it won't delete what was there before... This is why I am using setPixel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to fill in each line individually as you are doing, but note that you have to adjust the bounds of `x` for the radius. This is somewhat similar to doing a 2D (discrete) integration. The basic idea is that `x^2 + y^2 = r^2` at the outer bounds, and both `y` and `r` are fixed, so...:

```
for(int y = -r; y < r; y++)
{
    int bound = (int)(sqrt(r * r - y * y) + 0.5);
    for(int x = -bound; x < bound; x++)
    {
         raster.setPixel(x,y,color);
    }
}
```

`... + 0.5` is a safe way to round to the nearest integer (instead of just taking the `floor` with casting) since `bound` will always be positive.

Comment: Thanks! One problems though: you need to cast bound to int, otherwise perfect! Here is the output: http://imgur.com/c3V99EW